# Core data momd extension in Swift 2 and Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data

I upgraded the syntax on an app recently from `Swift 2` to `Swift 3` and the app now crashes with fatal `error`:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

**Swift 2** was:

```
    private lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .URLForResource(self.modelName,
            withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()
```

and the update to **Swift 3** is:

```
    private lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = Bundle.main
        .url(forResource: self.modelName,
                        withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()
```

What is it about Swift 3 that it does not like the "momd" extension? The app was working in Swift 2 and the user was able to build the data base from within the app without any pre-loading, so the url file modelName.momd was being created and used. The modelName is declared as:

```
let modelName = "GameCountPro"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line it's crashing on? You're using force unwrapping in two places, and either could be the cause.

Comment: Aloha Tom, the line the crash shows up on is: let modelURL = Bundle.main. url(forResource: self.modelName, with extension: "momd")!

Comment: Have you changed the name of the .xcdatamodel file?  That name will determine the correct name to use in the model url.

Comment: Good thought, I checked, in fact went back to the old version, copied and pasted the name of the model file in. Sadly, that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, did you have a solution to the problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the line in the AppDelegate

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CoreDataPractise", withExtension: "momd")!
```

The name in the `'forResource'` should exactly match your dataModel

```
"CoreDataPractise.xcdatamodeld".
```

Because Swift 3.1 doesn't give the CoreData stack boiler plate code, I copied all the lazy variables code from another old project , which actually had the datamodel named `"CoreDataDemo.xcdatamodeld"`. Due to this mismatch the app was crashing , although the crash at the 'forced unwrap' point was a redherring making you think it could be due to force-unwrap.

The `momd!` crash was resolved right after this fix.

In your case, check 'URLForResource(self.modelName,...' is exactly giving you the datamodel name that you have in the project and NOT a `"optional(dataModel name)"`